# Routh Stability criterion

Tags: control-theory, stability-in-odes

To check for the numbers of poles lying in the right side of the s-plane in a causal system, why do we check for the sign change only in first column ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at: wwwhome.math.utwente.nl/~meinsmag/reports/routh_tcns.pdf

"Elementary proof of the Routh-Hurwitz test" by Gjerrit Meinsma